# Cannot add another subsite link to global navigation in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Cannot add another subsite link to global navigation in sharepoint 2010, somehow is locked, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you Global Admin, is it Team Site?

Comment: If you're attempting to answer the question, it would be best not to phrase your answer as a question. If you're attempting to clarify something, doing so in an answer is not really appropriate. You should comment instead, which you'll be able to post with a bit more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a team site template:)

Comment: Funny, you have to uncheck sort automatically :)